# ASP.NET checkbox changes focus?

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, focus

I have a checkbox control, and when it's clicked, the focus of the page changes to the top--the window scrolls to the top of the page.

Nowhere in the code am I specifying a change in focus, either in JavaScript on codebehind.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Is the checkbox set with `Autopostback = true`?  This could cause the page to postback and reset the form.